# how to export database(dumpfile) into sqllite from mysql database in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I used `yaml_db` gem to create a dump file of my **mySQL** database to use with **SQLite**
However this is a full database export and I want to export data for specific table.

```
command = rake db:data:dump
```

Another way used

```
command:-mysqldump -uroot db_name table_name > db/database.yml
```

Those commands work for me but that they don't generate proper SQLite format. I think the format generated is SQL

How can I convert MySQL dump to SqLite.

Comment: How do you see for using bash?

for example:

script to convert mysql dump sql file into format that can be imported into sqlite3 db

https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776

Answer (score 0):

Since yaml_db gem works at db level, it has some functions that allow dowload only one table.

I wrote a patch that add a method to download only one table. Just put this code at `config/initializers/yaml_db_extras.rb`:

```
module YamlDb
  class Dump < SerializationHelper::Dump
    def self.dump_table_to_file(filename, table)
      file = File.new("#{filename}.yml", 'w')
      dump_table_columns(file, table)
      dump_table_records(file, table)
    end
  end
end
```

and use like this: `YamlDb::Dump.dump_table_to_file('db/dump_users','users')`, then you can use the dump file to load only the selected table at other app that uses yaml_db gem. If you name the dowload file `db/data.yml` at your destination app, you can load with `rake db:data:load`.